# Custom "Function" NetDecoder

Tags: neural-networks

I was surprised to learn that there is no custom "Function" named decoder for `NetDecoder`, as there is for `NetEncoder`. Has anyone perchance found a way to make a custom decoder with `NetDecoder`?

Comment: Yes, this definitely seems like a bit of an oversight! I've gotten around it in the past by reimplementing my netdecoder as a subnetwork, but that's no fun and doesn't extend well...

Comment: I think it's very likely that the developer forgot to add this.

Comment: Official support is coming in 12, I just asked on the livestream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save this as `*.m`

```
Input: RealTensorT

Parameters:
    $Function: FunctionT

ToDecoderFunction: Function[#Function]

Kind: "expression"
```

Then load this by:

```
<< NeuralNetworks`
file = "the path.m";
def = NeuralNetwork`Private`ReadDefinitionFile[file, "System`"];
NeuralNetworks`DefineDecoder["Function", def];
```

Let's do some test:

```
decoder=NetDecoder[{"Function",Image[#,Interleaving->False]&}]
net=NetChain[{ElementwiseLayer[#&]},"Output"->decoder]
net[RandomReal[1,{3,128,128}]]
```

[image]

But you still have to wait for official support, any custom behavior will cause the network cannot be imported back.

Comment: Wow, nicely found.